# subclassed python dictionary for custom namespace in exec() method

Tags: python, dictionary, namespaces, exec, subclass

I am trying to subclass a dictionary for use in an exec method.
Ultimately, I would like the local function to have a custom name scoping behaviour.

In the code below, function `b()` does in fact have the correct `globals()` dictionary available to it, however it fails to search it when resolving `z`.

Does function `b()` first not search `locals()` then `globals()` ?

Very puzzling.
Any help appreciated.

```
t = '''
def b():
#   return (globals()['z']) #works
    return z #fails

b()
'''

class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, g):
        dict.__init__(self)
        self.my_g = g


    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print("GET ", key)
        try:
            val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        except:
            print("GET exception1")
            val = self.my_g[key]
        return val


g = {'z':123}

md = MyDict(g)

#fails to find z
exec(t, md, md)

#works
#exec(t, g, g)
```

## output

```
GET  b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project1/text12", line 31, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in b
NameError: global name 'z' is not defined
```

Comment: return z fails because there is no variable z. You say return (globals()['z']) works, what do you want to accomplish when returning z?

Comment: I want the z to be resolved from the global dictionary passed in as working in the answer below. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before python 3.3, you **cannot** use a custom `dict` subclass for the `globals` value of an exec statement. The underlying C code that executes the compiled code accesses the underlying C structures directly, ignoring any custom hooks you may have implemented.

In other words, when the code does a `LOAD_GLOBAL` operation (as is the case with `z` in your function `b`), the C bytecode evaluation loop accesses the `globals` structure in the current frame using the [C API](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/dict.html), bypassing any python overrides.

This is documented in the [`exec()` function documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#exec) as:

> If only *globals* is provided, it must be a dictionary, which will be used for both the global and the local variables. If *globals* and *locals* are given, they are used for the global and local variables, respectively. If provided, *locals* can be any mapping object.

This restriction has been loosened in Python 3.3, see [issue 14385](http://bugs.python.org/issue14385). The documentation hasn't been updated yet, but the bytecode evaluation loop has been updated to test for custom mappings before falling back to the C API access. If a custom mapping is used, the `PyObject_GetItem` function is used, which will call `__getitem__` on custom classes.

Comment: thank you very much. I havent had a chance to work this back into my original work but it looks great. Thanks again -Rob

Comment: Sorry @martijn-pieters , its not quite there yet.  Your addition works for finding variables in the local scope, but not in the function scope as the original example has.

Im also using Python 3.2 if thats relevant.

In other words:
t = 'print(z)' now works

but:

t = '''
def b():
    return z
b()
''' still fails.

Any insight as to how to get the function scope to search the globals dictionary in that case, as it does when I pass in g directly? Thanks.

Comment: @rbairos: that's what I explained in the first half; unbound variables in the function scope are always looked up in the `global()` scope next. There is no module-local scope here that normally also puts things in the `global()` scope.

Comment: But, @martijn-pieters  isnt the global() scope the dictionary I pass in as an argument to exec() ? ie. exec(t, md, md) ?  Confused as to why it doesnt attempt to search md, as it searches g when I call (t,g,g) ?  (sorry this subtlety is new to me)

Comment: @rbairos: investigating a little if python 3 makes a difference.

Comment: hmm. @martijn-pieters Is that a bug?  The z inside the function **is** looked up when I call:  exec(t,g,g) though. How does python3.2 know to act differently when I call: exec(t,md,md) ?

Comment: @rbairos: ah, it was my own mistake, it works as expected in py3k too. Now moving on to your custom class and py3k.

Comment: @rbairos: I cannot get *any* custom dict class to work yet in py3k. The [documentation on `exec()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#exec) does state that `globals` *must* be a dict while `locals` can be a mapping. A quick scan of the Python source didn't reveal any differences yet. Tomorrow perhaps.

Comment: Thanks very much @martijn-pieters, youre help and expertise is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Hi @martijn-pieters.  I just discovered the sample code fails in Python3.2, but **works** in Python 3.3  Thats very interesting. Luckily the candidate release was released 6 days ago. Hopefully its stable.

Comment: @rbairos: interesting indeed; after retesting and thorough reading of the source code I came to the conclusion it won't work under all released versions up to 3.2. Will look at 3.3 now.

Comment: @rbairos: very cool, the restriction is indeed lifted in 3.3; answer updated to point to the issue report and what changed.

Comment: Excellent. @martijn-pieters  Thanks for verifying. I think this question is sufficiently answered! Cheers

Comment: It looks like `LOAD_NAME` hasn't been adjusted. It still uses `PyDict_GetItem` directly to read globals. `STORE_GLOBAL` and `DELETE_GLOBAL` also still use `PyDict_SetItem` and `PyDict_DelItem`, bypassing any custom hooks. I wonder if any of this should be considered a bug.

Comment: @user2357112: perhaps follow up in [the issue that meant to fix all this](https://bugs.python.org/issue14385)?

Comment: @user2357112: I also found [this older issue on the same subject](https://bugs.python.org/issue1402289) which looks orphaned now.